# background services in Titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

In my application I need to sync my local database with web server. Now I can able to sync with web server, but I need to do this as background service(like gmail sync). How do I do background service in Titanium (both Android and iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titanium Service for Android and ios platform

[Android Services](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Simple+Android+Services+in+Titanium)

[iOS Services](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119966/stopstart-ios-background-service)

Note that you will have to handle this different in each platform.